# AJAX loaded html not using external JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My Set up:

Im using Laravel and blade.

- i have a post.blade.php file which extends a blog.blade.php (master page)
- in the master.blade.php file, i load all my external scripts right before the `</body>` tag:

Example:

```
 @if (!App::environment('local'))
      <script src="{{ elixir('js/libs.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ elixir('js/public.js') }}"></script>
 @else
      <script src="{{ asset('js/libs.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/public.js') }}"></script>
 @endif

 @yield('scripts')
```

- in my post.blade.php file, i have `@section('scripts')` section which is yielded underneath the externally loaded JS (see example above).

In the JS on the post.blade.php file (in the `@section('scripts')`) , i dynamically load a form using ajax

```
if(ctaSnippet.length){
    //insert html in div
    $.get('/blog-snippet', function(data){
        ctaSnippet.html(data);
    });
}
```

Up to now, everything works fine. the form gets loaded into the page as intended. the problem is when i try to submit the form. the JS logic for form submissions is located in the externally loaded public.js file. basically, the form is supposed to be posted through ajax and return a json response. But for some reason, it ignores the JS in the public.js and submits normally ( gets redirected to the location in the action attribute). if i attach the ajax loaded form's submit event using JQuery's `.on()` and copy paste the form submission script from the public.js into the handler function, it works fine. the problem is, it's messy and would prefer not to.  What i want to know is, is there a way to submit the ajax loaded form using the external javascript, and not having to copy paste the script into the .on handler function.

i hope i worded my problem properly. thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you binding the Ajax call to the submit action?

Comment: You just need to use the `on()` handler in the external file.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky wow...that worked....i feel so dumb for not thinking about that